# Remove text from a String Covert to Integer

Tags: excel, vba, string, text, integer

How do I remove text from a string "MIC-CT-001", and convert the numbers to an Integer, where I can add 1 to the numeric, convert back to a string and push back to the Spreadsheet?

```
Public Function UniqueID()

Call SetVariables

DIM LastID as String
DIM LastNumber as Integer
DIM NextNumber as Integer
DIM NextID as Integer

LastID = xTracker.Range("B" & tRow).Value

'==========================
'Remove text from string
'==========================

NextNumber = LastNumber+1
NextID = ("MIC-CT-" & NextNumber)

End Function
```

Unfortunately this is as far as I can go without removing the text from the string and converting it to an Integer.

Comment: `Split` should be helpful here.

Comment: Got to admit, I’m a novice when it comes to Coding. I’ve never come across the Spilt Function before.

Comment: Tried using LastNo = Split(LastID,”MIC-CT-“,1) where LastID as String, and LastNo () as Integer. But come up with a Mismatch. If I try CInt(Split(LastID,”MIC-CT-“,1) is also fails

Comment: Is your number always 3 digits long? Is the rest of the text always "Mic-Ct-"?

Comment: No the number increases, the text is always the same. Hence why I am trying to extract the numbers and convert to Integer, add 1 to the number and re-package.

Comment: `CLng(Replace("MIC-CT-001", "MIC-CT-", ""))` will return the numeric value (the number 1 in the example). From there, you can format the numeric value as a string, recreate the `MIC...` value. Of course, this is predicated upon the fact that text component is always "MIC-CT-". If this can vary, we'd have to get a bit more creative.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. This has resolved the problem, using the replace function has allowed me to do what I needed.

Comment: You sure you need VBA for such a simple task?

Comment: Yes because it is done via a userform. The UniqueID is the most important field. It pulls information from a number of tabs and writes it back to the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want do do 2 things.

*"Removing the text from the string":* Use Replace for this. As you are about to use "MIC-CT-" multiple times, consider to create a new variable for it. This gives you more flexibility and you don't have to change this string everywhere in your code once your requirements change. Please keep in mind that the examples below work only if LastNumber is declared as a string.

```
Dim Mic as String
Mic = "MIC-CT-"

LastNumber = replace(xTracker.Range("B" & tRow).Value, Mic, "")
```

*"Converting it to an Integer."* You can use Cint(expression) for this.

```
NextNumber=Cint(LastNumber) + 1 'Changes the data type of LastNumber to integer
```

Put this together and your script should work.